# how to insert filenames with single quotes in a postgresql COPY command from delphi, parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, delphi, parameters, pascal

I'm having some fun trying to include a filename in a Postgresql script in delphi, the desired string is

```
  COPY myschema.mytable FROM 'c:\data\data.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

I know this SQL query is parsed ok by postgresql as I've tested it in pgadmin, the problem is how to generate it in Delphi. Delphi uses single quotes for strings, so even using the QuotedStr method like

```
TempSQL := 'COPY myschema.mytable FROM '+QuotedStr(myfilename)+ ' CSV HEADER';
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add (TempSQL);
```

the string is generated as

```
COPY myschema.mytable FROM ''c:\data\data.csv'' CSV HEADER;
```

So I'm trying to use Parameters.ParamByName like

```
TempSQL := 'COPY myschema.mytable FROM :PFileName CSV HEADER';
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add (TempSQL);
FileNameParam := LQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('PFileName');
FileNameParam.DataType := ftstring;
FileNameParam.Value := 'c:\data\data.csv';
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Gives the error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"; Error while executing the query. $1 is usually caused by paramnames being the same as column names, thats not the case here, I tried different paramnames. I think the problem is that maybe Parambyname doesn't work for this type of argument, it's normally used like

```
    SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE myfield = :myparameter
```

ie the colon comes after an = which isn't the case with the copy command. Any suggestions welcome. The delphi code basically scans a directory for (1000s of) suitable files and keeps a log of what is imported, maybe I have to interface with the db in a different way entirely.

Comment: What happens if you try `TempSQL := 'COPY myschema.mytable FROM '''+myfilename+ ''' CSV HEADER';` Note the space before `CSV HEADER`

Comment: With triple quotes, it parses the outer 2 single quotes as double quotes like (" 'filename' ")and returns ERROR: could not open file "'c:\data\data.csv'" for reading: Invalid argument
SQL state: XX000

Comment: With double quotes it returns this error  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c"
LINE 1: COPY myschema.mytable FROM ''c:\data\data.csv...
                                     ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "c"
SQL state:42601
Character:43

Comment: The code in your first example doesn't match the given output; `TempSQL` would not have a space before "CSV". Are you sure you haven't left anything else out?

Comment: sorry, I have inserted the missing space in the original question. spacings between commands are all present in the actual script which are copied from the delphi ide to pgadmin to double check, which is the reason for the intermediate tempsql string variable.

Comment: Keith, I realise I didn't follow your syntax exactly, if you have 3 quotes followed by a +symbol, then the +symbols will appear in the actual string like 'COPY myschema.mytable FROM '' + myfilename + '' CSV HEADER;'

Comment: Did you write out the string, you got from the QuotedStr method? Does Writeln(TempSQL) really write two quotes or is '' just the escaped quote?

Comment: sqlab - Thankyou! I realise now that the rightclick>copvalue feature to check parameters in the delphi IDE>object inspector does not give the same output as showmessage(TempSQL) or Writeln(TempSQL). So the QuotedStr method does work after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfectly in a quick test app, and displays the properly quoted string in the call to `ShowMessage`, which means there's something other than what you've shown us here going on in your code.

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TempStr: string;
  MyFileName: string;
begin
  MyFileName := 'somefile.txt';
  TempStr := 'COPY myschema.mytable FROM ' + QuotedStr(myfilename) + ' CSV HEADER';
  ShowMessage(TempStr);
end
```

The resulting dialog:

[image: Image showing properly quoted string in ShowMessage dialog]

Comment: Ken, yes, I now realise now that the rightclick>copvalue feature to check parameters in the delphi IDE>object inspector does not give the same output as showmessage(TempSQL) or Writeln(TempSQL). So the QuotedStr method does work after all. –